# Storing a weak reference to a UITableView cell without causing memory leaks

Tags: swift, uitableview, memory-leaks

I think I'm understanding the `weak` keyword properly, but wanted to quickly sense check that I'm not doing something wrong.

I'm wanting to store a reference to a specific `UITableViewCell` so that I can call functions or edit values when needed. Now I don't need to be able to edit the values all the time, only when it's on screen so I don't need to keep a hard copy of the cell at all times. What I've done is as follows:

```swift
class customTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  var variable1: String?

  func doAThing(index: Int) {
    self.variable1 = "did a thing"
  }
}

class MainView: UIView {
  weak var cellToManipulate: CustomTableViewCell?

  func manipulateCell() {
    self.cellToManipulate?.doAThing(index: 1)
  }
}
```

Obviously there will be a tableview and everything else involved, but if I store a weak reference to a cell, it will be removed from memory and set to nil when the tableview scrolls right? 
Is there maybe a better way to go about this, aside from `forEach`ing through each item in the visibleCells array?

Comment: Please explain more about your problem, may be we can find a better way to do your need. Probably your logic isn't correct way to update cell / data.

Comment: The cell will be reused as it scrolls off-screen. I think you should be making the changes to your underlying data model, then have the cell at the appropriate index path reflect that.